# How to set a clear button in textfield for android in titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to set a clear button in text field using clearbuttonmode where it is working fine with Ios Platform and is not showing up in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `clearButtonMode` (check your spelling) is only available for iOS as you can see in the documentation I would go the multiplatform way and create a own button and add it next to the TextField. The buttons just sets the TextField value to `""` to clear the field. You could even put everything inside a `<View>` with a white background and a border so it will look like the clear Button is inside the TextField

pseudo code:

```
<View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="300">
  <TextField left="0" right="40"/>
  <Button width="40" right="0"/>
</View>
```